# Symfongy Custom Form Type: Why i can not get the uploaded data?

Tags: upload, symfony

Symfony version: 3.0

In my entity has a field to store the uploaded file path. I need to custom the upload field template, so i made a custom field type for the file field.

Entity/Store.php:

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
private $thumbnail;

/**
 * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
 *
 * @var File
 */
private $thumbnailFile;

/**
 * Set thumbnail
 *
 * @param string $thumbnail
 *
 * @return Store
 */
public function setThumbnail($thumbnail)
{
    $this->thumbnail = $thumbnail;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get thumbnail
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getThumbnail()
{
    return $this->thumbnail;
}

/**
 * If manually uploading a file (i.e. not using Symfony Form) ensure an instance
 * of 'UploadedFile' is injected into this setter to trigger the  update. If this
 * bundle's configuration parameter 'inject_on_load' is set to 'true' this setter
 * must be able to accept an instance of 'File' as the bundle will inject one here
 * during Doctrine hydration.
 *
 * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $file
 *
 * @return Store
 */
public function setThumbnailFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    $this->thumbnailFile = $file;

    if ($file) {
        // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
        // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now');
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return File
 */
public function getThumbnailFile()
{
    return $this->thumbnailFile;
}
```

StoreType.php:

```
->add('thumbnailFile', SingleThumbnailType::class, array(
    'required' => false,
    'mapped' => false
))
```

SingleThumbnailType.php:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class SingleThumbnailType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('singleThumbnail', FileType::class);
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $parentData = $form->getParent()->getData();
        $uploadedeUrl = '/uploads/';
        $view->vars['thumbnail_url'] = $uploadedeUrl . 'product-default.jpg';
        if($parentData->getThumbnail()) {
            $view->vars['thumbnail_url'] = $uploadedeUrl . $parentData->getThumbnail();
        }
    }
}
```

When i selected the image and submitted, i got the error message:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: "Expected argument of type "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File", "array" given" at /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php line 254 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\PropertyAccess\\Exception\\InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Expected argument of type \"Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\File\\File\", \"array\" given at /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php:254)"} []
```

I debug the $request data, the thumbnailFile is null in the store object data.

I use `dump($form->getErrors(true));` got this message below:

```
FormErrorIterator {#948 ▼
  -form: Form {#591 ▶}
  -errors: array:1 [▼
    0 => FormError {#936 ▼
      -message: "This value is not valid."
      #messageTemplate: "This value is not valid."
      #messageParameters: array:1 [▼
        "{{ value }}" => "object"
      ]
      #messagePluralization: null
      -cause: ConstraintViolation {#925 ▶}
      -origin: Form {#609 ▼
        -config: FormBuilder {#610 ▶}
        -parent: Form {#591}
        -children: OrderedHashMap {#611 ▶}
        -errors: []
        -submitted: true
        -clickedButton: null
        -modelData: null
        -normData: null
        -viewData: UploadedFile {#22 ▶}
        -extraData: []
        -transformationFailure: TransformationFailedException {#818 ▶}
        -defaultDataSet: true
        -lockSetData: false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But if i use the filetype directory on parent form type(StoreType.php not SingleThumbnailType.php), i can get the thumbnail data.

```
->add('thumbnailFile', FileType::class, array(
'required' => false,
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to 'thumbnailFile' `FileType::class,array('data_class' => null)`

Comment: not work for me. the $form->isValid() is false still. thanks. i have added the error message above.